# How do I change the src of an image based on input value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

My code looks like this. If the value of textbox is empty it display an image abc.png
If the value of a textbox is some value, it displays other image xyz.png

```
<td class= 'notesClass' id='selectoneN'>
    <a href='#'>
        <img class='notesImg' id='notesID' src='images/notes.png'/>
        <input class='hiddenClass'  value="+Col7+"></input>
    </a>
</td>
```

I have used `$('table tr td img').attr("src", "images/xyz.png");`
but the problem is it replaces all img with xyz.png which is not what I want.

Comment: do you have identical id's for your td's?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#id_of_image")[0].src = "images/xyz.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

So use `$('#notesID').attr("src", "images/xyz.png");` to target just that one `img` by its `id`

`#notesID` is essentially saying to jquery that you want to target an element by its ID (`#` does this, where `.` would target a css class) - along with the actual ID `notesID`

your selector - `$('table tr td img')` - is is targeting ALL images in a table in a cell of a row of a table.

Answer (score 0):

use `id` to address

```
$('#notesID').attr(...)
```

and if image is cashed, send time as a parameter

```
var now = new Date();
$('#notesID').attr('src', 'path/to/image?'+now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note your selector:

```
$('table tr td img')
```

This will target *any* `img` which is in *any* table.  So if there's more than one, you're applying the logic to all of them.  However, notice your markup:

```
<img class='notesImg' id='notesID' ...
```

Your element has an `id`.  `id`s are required to be unique, so assuming you're not breaking that rule you can easily target that element:

```
$('#notesID')
```

If, on the other hand, you *are* breaking that rule, well, stop it.  But more to the point that would mean you don't have a unique identifier for the element you're targeting.  So, logically (not in terms of code but just in terms of the document structure), how would you *identify* that element?

For example, what is the JavaScript code which invokes this?  Is it responding to an event handler?  Is that event handler attached to the `input` element?  Is there a `this` reference to that `input` element?  If so, you can identify its neighboring `img` a couple of ways.  This might work:

```
$(this).prev('img')
```

or perhaps something like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('img')
```

Essentially it's traversing the DOM from the known starting point (the `input`) to find the nearby `img`.  You can move backward or forward in the DOM, or move up to a common parent and back down.  It's a basic hierarchical structure that can be [navigated by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).  Once you can logically identify how you would decide which element to choose, it's just a matter of using a jQuery selector (or combination of them) to express that logic.